# PHP Contact Form - make the Reply-To to have the submitter email

Tags: php, email, contacts, contact-form

I inspected different topics there, but all of them are not working with my code. I need to get the ability to answer direct to submitter email via my email. Here is my code:

```
    <?php

// configure
$from = '<mymail@gmail.com>';
$sendTo = '<mymail@gmail.com>';
$subject = 'New message from PROMO form';
$fields = array('name' => 'Name', 'city' => 'City', 'tel' => 'Tel', 'email' => 'Email', 'message' => 'Message', 'age' => 'Age', 'info' => 'Info', 'checkboxtwo' => 'Checkboxtwo'); // array variable name
$okMessage = 'Спасибо.';
$errorMessage = 'Извините, ошибка.';
$headers = 'From: ' . $fields['email'] . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $fields['email'];

try
{
    $emailText = "You have new message from online form form\n=============================\n";

    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {

        if (isset($fields[$key])) {
            $emailText .= "$fields[$key]: $value\n";
        }
    }

    mail($sendTo, $subject, $emailText, $headers);

    $responseArray = array('type' => 'success', 'message' => $okMessage);
}
catch (\Exception $e)
{
    $responseArray = array('type' => 'danger', 'message' => $errorMessage);
}

if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
    $encoded = json_encode($responseArray);

    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    echo $encoded;
}
else {
    echo $responseArray['message'];
}
```

I will highly appreciate any help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**THE ANSWER**

Re-write your foreach like this:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        if (isset($fields[$key])) {
            $emailText .= "$fields[$key]: $value\n";
            $fields[$key] = $value; //It set the values on the array
        }
}
```

Then add the headers:

```
$headers = 'From: ' . $fields['email'] . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $fields['email'];
```

So just send the mail.

```
mail($sendTo, $subject, $emailText, $headers);
```

**Other answers (ignore them)**

Just set the headers with the "Reply-To".

```
$headers = 'From: ' . $from . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $from;

mail($sendTo, $subject, $emailText, $headers);
```

You will get any replies to the email that you used to submit the message.

**EDIT**

Get the desired email by using this:

```
$sendTo = $fields['email'];
```

Then you will be able to send the email using this var.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I dont need to reply to $from - it`s my email. I need to get the ability to reply to email which is one element of this array - $fields = array('name' => 'Name', 'city' => 'City', 'tel' => 'Tel', 'email' => 'Email', 'message' => 'Message', 'age' => 'Age', 'info' => 'Info', 'checkboxtwo' => 'Checkboxtwo');

Comment: So you want to send a message to email in the array, right?

Comment: Yes, exactly that email is from submitter.

Comment: Please, see the "EDIT" here for the correct answer.

Comment: I am sorry, but I am not sure that we understand each other correct. I receive emails via website. Currently, if I click on reply button in gmail - I get my email to reply. I want to reply directly to the email from $fields.

Comment: Please specify. Do you want to get the email of the user who sent a message to you and add that to the array? Do you want a page where you can write a message to reply or what?

Comment: The procedure currently. 1)Some user submits the form. 2)I receive this form via my email. 3)If I want to reply to this email - I can do this only to my email. What I want - I want to reply directly to submitters email (not to my email). Thank you very much.

Comment: If you're using a database, just run a query on that to get these infos, then add to the array on your script, ref the $sendTo as I did on the "EDIT" code and send the mail. You can search for more infos about database and queries by looking for "mysqli" on Google or whatever you prefer (if you're using MySQL, of course). I can't understand your doubt if it's not that.

Comment: I dont use any database. The code above does the sending. That`s all. I think you are on the right way. How can I add that email to headers correct?

Comment: I recommend you to do the following (that's the only way I know to do it): Every time that a users sends you a email by the form, you add a ticket number to the database, with it, save the users's email. Before the users sending, put the ticket number on the subject. E.g: "#TicketNumber - user subject". You'll will receive the email with the ticket. Then search for the ticket number on database, pick up the email that corresponds to it and just reply. Please consider learning databases (I recommend MySQL), it's very easy and you'll be ready to go in some hours).

Comment: Thank you for this answer, but I think your previous answer was better. How can I modify your code to work correct? I mean how to add correctly $fields['email']; to $headers = 'From: ' . $from . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $from;? I think correct reply-to in headers will do this task.

Comment: Oh, I think I got it. If the script you wrote here is the script that the user uses to send you the email, all that you need to do to achieve your objective is replace the $headers var by: $headers = 'From: ' . $fields['email'] . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $fields['email'];

Comment: Thank you for your help. I edited the code and the post there. Now, there is my actual code. But if I get the email - I receive it from hosting mail - 
Email@skm123.hostsila.org and $fields['email']; is not working. Maybe I did something wrong while editing? Please, take a look at updated code.

Comment: The code runs after the user write the form. Right? If it's running after the user submiting, you'll need to pass the FORM values (usually POST). So you have the "<form method='POST'> bla bla bla </form>". You'll need to refer the $_POST name of the input on the array. So, suposing that the name of the email input on your HTML is "email", on the array you'll need to refer it like: ... 'email' => $_POST['email'], ...
Are you doing it?

Comment: Yes, I have the "<form method='POST'> bla bla bla </form>". Everything work, I receive all required data in email. But I dont get the $fields['email']; in from and reply field in my gmail. All form values are in the array, you can see my modified code above.

Comment: Please replace your foreach by:

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {

        if (isset($fields[$key])) {
            $emailText .= "$fields[$key]: $value\n";
            $fields[$key] = $value;
        }
    }

Then refer the $headers (don't refer before the foreach): $headers = 'From: ' . $fields['email'] . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $fields['email'];

So hopefully it all will be ok.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now everything is correct. Thank you one more time.